# High traffic solution for simple data graph website

Tags: javascript, ruby, xml, sinatra, highcharts

I'm building a single page website that will display dynamic data (updating once a second) via a graph to its users. I'm expecting this page to receive a large amount of traffic.

My data is stored in [REDIS](http://redis.io/) and I'm displaying the graph using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). I'm using ruby / Sinatra as my application layer.

My question is how best should I architecture the link between the data store and the JavaScript graph solution?

I've considered directly connecting to REDIS but that seems the least efficient . I'm wondering whether a XML solution where ruby builds an XML file every second and then Highcharts pulls data from there is the best as therefore the stress is only on hitting that XML file.

But I wanted to see whether anyone on here might have solved this previously or had any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is not user-specific, you should cache it into a representation that is easily read by the client. With web browsers, **JSON** might be a [better choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636245/choosing-between-json-and-xml).

You can cache it using Redis itself. ([Memcached](http://memcached.org/), [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) are other options) You should cache it every time the data arrives and must avoid transforming the data on each request. The requests must simply serve pre-computed information from the cache (like you do with static information)

For a better experience on the client side, you should minimize the amount of data you are downloading from the server. JSON serves this purpose better than XML.

Comment: Thanks Elvis - will look at JSON.